# database issues magento CE 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, database

I might be off topic, but I don't where to ask.
DaMysql crashes quite often during night scripts. Some are Databases backups, but not all.

How could I address this issue ? I am sure there are many.

Comment: How big is the database? What sort of server do you have? Have you cleaned your log files?

Comment: Database: 8.4 Go
Server: CentOS
Total processors: 8

Yes we cleaned the log files..
We should probably look at the .conf file of Apache. And use a mysql dedicated server. What is your diagnosis ?
Processors:

    Vendor
        GenuineIntel

    Name
        Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5520 @ 2.27GHz

    Speed
        2266.969 MHz

    Cache
        8192 KB

Comment: anyone there ? I suppled the answers..

Answer (score 0):

Could be a disk space issue especially if it's during backups.

If you can log into your server via ssh and run the following command

```
df -h
```

You should see something like this.
[image]

It may also be worth using something like phpmyadmin or sequelPro to optimize and repair any databases, if they are magento scripts running check the logs for more information (var/log/exception.log and system.log)

Mysql will have it's own logs too in the root of the server that will also help in var/log/

It's most likely a disk/space error but that's just speculation as it's one of the most common issues

Comment: what is a disk space issue ?

Comment: I ran df -h, but can't display the image. For some reason, stackstuff won't allow me to. How should I interpret what I get ?

Comment: By Disk space issue i mean running out of disk space, as mysql requires space on the disk to create temporary files and log files.

You should have a column called Use% or Used% are any of them close to 100%?